# How do I see the negotiated wireless speed in Windows 7 and OS X

Tags: windows-7, macos, wireless-networking, speed

In Windows XP when I connected to a network it would list the speed at which I connected, e.g. 54 mbps, 11 mbps, etc.  Where can I see the same information in in either Windows 7 or OS X?

Since upgrading from XP I cannot see this info in Windows 7 and I've never been able to see it in OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MacOS X if you hold down the Option key and click on the wireless setting and it will show what speed you are connecting at. It will be listed as Transmit Rate under the network that you are connected to.

In Windows 7 if you get properties on the wireless network that you are connected to and the properties window will show the speed that it is connected at.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, if you right-click on the wireless connection on the taskbar, click 'STATUS' on the wireless network that you are connected to and the properties window will show the speed that it is connected at.